# Sum of a column with distinct ID?

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a table that has multiple IDs and need a query to return the sum of a column for each ID. Calls_table looks like this

```
EmployeeID    TypeOfCall    InvoiceAmount 
John          NC             50
john          NC             100
Joe           NC             76
Joe           NC             50
```

i have it so i have to do it employee by emplyee now like

```
SELECT sum(InvoiceAmount/2) as "Total Calls" 
from Calls
where TypeOfCall='NC' and EmployeeID='Derek';
```

but i would like it to be able to return all IDs in a list like this

```
Total Calls
Joe              100
John             68
```

I am sure i need to use the Distinct parameter but just cant figure out where

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the group by keyword

```
Select EmployeeID, SUM(InvoiceAmount) 
From Calls
Group by EmployeeID
```

You can even take it a bit further and group by type of call and EmployeeID like This:

```
Select EmployeeID, TypeOfCall, SUM(InvoiceAmount) 
From Calls
Group by EmployeeID, TypeOfCall
```

Your selected fields need to be either aggregate functions (sum, count, avg, etc) or in the Group by when doing this.

Comment: god i feel retarded. thank you. i took a class on this but all the instructor taught us was how to create tables and basic queries so im digging deeper.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(InvoiceAmount/2)
FROM Calls
WHERE TypeOfCall='NC'
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```